# php getting sum from foreach loop

Tags: php, algorithm, foreach

Hi how is it possible to get sum from foreach loop for the following case:

```
price = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
            [1] => 400
        )
)
```

how can i get average value sum of each elements? i need to add

```
avg1 = price[0][0] + price[1][0] .... + price[N][0]
avg2 = price[0][1] + price[1][1] .... + price[N][1]
```

then divide by num of elements. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, could you show a sample of output you are looking for?

Comment: @enginefree need average sum of all price[0][0] price[1][0] and average sum of price[0][1] price[1][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php


 $price = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            0 => 100,
            1 => 200,
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            0 => 300,
            1 => 400,
        )
);
$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$i  = 0;
foreach($price as $p)
{
    $a += $p[0];
    $b += $p[1];
    $i++;
}
echo 'Avg of a= '. ($a/$i).PHP_EOL;
echo 'Avg of b= '. ($b/$i).PHP_EOL;
?>
```

It is a simple clue....you can build it in your own idea

Comment: how about average sum for each of them?

Comment: why do i get $i = 10 ? i only have 4 arrays

Comment: I don't pickup ur question?

Comment: what is $i stand for? when i echo $i at end of line i got 10

Comment: $result_pricing = $businessReviewMapper->getAllPricing($bid);
  $prc_avg = array();
  $a = 0;
  $b = 0;
  $i = 0;
  
  foreach($result_pricing as $prc){
   
   $prc_avg[] = array_map("intval",explode(",",$prc['pricing']));
   foreach($prc_avg as $p){
    $a += $p[0];
    $b += $p[1];
    $i++;
   }
   
  }

Comment: the result i get something like 7.5.

Comment: use foreach($result_pricing as $prc){ $prc_avg[] = array_map("intval",explode(",",$prc['pricing'])); } foreach($prc_avg as $p){ $a += $p[0]; $b += $p[1]; $i++;  }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27677/discussion-between-tamil-selvan-and-saraswathi-apavoo)

Comment: what is difference the code i paste than yours?

Comment: you used as foreach() { foreach() { ..... $i++ } }
Now $i is increment for each foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$price = array();
$price[0][0] = 100;
$price[0][1] = 200;
$price[1][0] = 300;
$price[1][1] = 400;
$price[2][0] = 500;
$price[2][1] = 600;

$sum1 = 0; $sum2 = 0;
$count1 = 0; $count2 = 0;

foreach($price as $array){
   if (isset($array[0])){
      $sum1+=$array[0];
      $count1++;
   }
   if (isset($array[1])){
      $sum2+=$array[1];
      $count2++;
   }
}

$ave1 = sprintf("%2.f", $sum1/$count1);
$ave2 = sprintf("%2.f", $sum2/$count2);
print "$ave1\n$ave2\n\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i =0; $i < count($i): $i++){
   $avg = 0;
   for($j =0; $i < $j: $j++){
        $avg = $avg + $price[$j][$i] ;        
   }
   echo "avg$i: $avg";
}
```